# Rolling back an unsaved record? Cancelling an edit of a record should revert to its state prior to the edit, not to the blank state

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my app, i let the user create a record on clientside and fiddle with it prior to saving. The record is of a pretty complex model with a lot of realtionships. To edit the record, a modal dialog opens and displays a form.

Example scenario:

1. You've created a new record on client side. It's in the blank state.
2. Then you proceed to edit the record. You make changes to the form in the modal dialog and press OK. The record now is in state A.
3. Then you proceed to edit the record again, turning the record to state B. But this time you mess the form up and decide to Cancel.

When you hit Cancel, the record should revert to state A.

The problem is that this is an unsaved record and thus `record.rollback()` can not be used.

All i could think of is making a copy of a record and feeding it to the form. But most of the form's fields are bound to related records, thus, you'd have to clone the record's related records recursively. This is a huge hack that i don't want to go for.

Any simpler suggestions?

Comment: maybe you just want to sync the data with the server, so actually save the state A? then, you don't have the problem... I know it's not what you're asking about but maybe you're trying to make it complex without a reason :)

Comment: We don't want the backend to save records that will not be necessary afterwards. Consider this a backendless use case.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I have used is based on the buffered proxy pattern within my controllers.

This way your controller can just throw away the buffer on cancel or apply the buffer to models and orchestrate model saves when the user OKs the changes.

Here is an ember package you can use to get started: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-buffered-proxy

Comment: Thank you for you answer, namesake! I'm still puzzled how to use it with records. I guess i can mix it into my models, but this doesn't solve the problem that most of data is stored in related records rather than the record in question. Can you please fix up an example?

Comment: Just mix into your controllers. The buffer proxy will cache any model property changes. I'm not at my  computer right now but I'll add some example code when i get back

Comment: Into controllers? O_o